# Docker container inside docker container - how to mount volumes?

Tags: docker, mounted-volumes

I have a `containerA` that creates other containers (B, C, D). I'm trying to mount a directory from containers B, C, and D to container A.

How I run `containerA`

`docker run --security-opt="apparmor=unconfined" --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(pwd):/app -it --rm parentContainer`

After `containerA` is created, it runs a script that creates other containers using

`docker run --security-opt=apparmor=unconfined --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --pid=container:"***" -t -v $(pwd)/contaner_b/logs:/app/logs childContainer`

Unfortunately, any files created within child containers are not mounted in the `containerA` (parent container)

What works is manual `docker cp "containerB:/app/logs" /app/container_b/logs"` executed in the `containerA`, but I don't like this approach to be honest. Am I missing something here? Can I make mounts work?

Comment: The `docker run -v` option is always interpreted by the Docker daemon; whatever context the Docker daemon is in, its `.../container_b` directory is mounted into the container.  You can't mount one container's non-volume directory into another container.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for the answer! Do I understand it right that in this case my only option is to execute `docker cp` manually to grab logs from child containers?